# Is it possible to run pluginkit from a process running as root?

Tags: macos, unix, launchd, osx-extensions

I'm trying to run `pluginkit` (The executable that manages extensions on OS X) from a launch daemon running as root.

`/usr/bin/pluginkit -m -i "<identifier>"` fails with an output of `match: Connection invalid`. This is not terribly unexpected, since extension settings are handled on a per-user basis.

However, I've tried to use `su` to run `pluginkit` as a normal user, and it still doesn't work.

`su <username> -l -c "/usr/bin/pluginkit -m -i "<identifier>"` also fails with an output of `match: Connection invalid`.

Somehow the environment that pluginkit is running in is still different enough from a normal user that it doesn't work properly. Is there anyway to run pluginkit as root? Or is there any other way to launch a process as another user that might provide a more complete environment?

I'm testing this with a command line tool written in Swift:

**main.swift**

```
import Foundation

let task = NSTask()

// Option 1: Run pluginkit directly
task.launchPath="/usr/bin/pluginkit"
task.arguments = ["-m", "-i", "com.example.findersyncext"]

// Option 2: Run pluginkit as <username> using 'su'
//task.launchPath="/usr/bin/su"
//task.arguments = ["<username>", "-l", "-c", "/usr/bin/pluginkit -m -i \"com.example.findersyncext\""]

// Option 3: Run pluginkit as <username> using 'sudo'
//task.launchPath="/usr/bin/sudo"
//task.arguments = ["-u", "<username>", "/usr/bin/pluginkit", "-m", "-i", "com.example.findersyncext"]

task.standardOutput = NSPipe()
task.standardError = NSPipe()
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()

NSLog("Exit code: \(task.terminationStatus)")
let output = NSString(data: (task.standardOutput!.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
NSLog("Output: \(output)")

let error = NSString(data: (task.standardError!.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
NSLog("Error: \(error)")
```

**/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.PluginKitTest.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.PluginKitTest</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/path/to/PluginKitTest</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/<username>/Desktop/pluginkit-error.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/<username>/Desktop/pluginkit-out.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: It might help to show your .plist for the daemon, and the location of it on your system.

Comment: Updated with the plist and the command line tool that is invoked.

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/a/832673/94915; also you might need to add  `<key>UserName</key>` in the plist.

Comment: No luck, adding a UserName key to the plist causes the launch daemon to run as the user without sudo privileges.

Comment: The thinking with `<key>UserName</key>` is to set it to the `root` user — you might give that a try.

Comment: Any updates on this? Having the same issue.

Comment: @StefanSzekeres I actually was able to solve this! I just added an answer explaining what solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is additional user context that is not set by the `su` command, that needs to be set by using the command `launchctl asuser`. So, I was able to solve my problem by updating my command to invoke both `launchctl asuser` and `su` to update all aspects of the context:

`launchctl asuser $USER_UID su $USER_UID -c "<command>"`

According to the documentation of `launchctl asuser`:

> Adopted attributes include the Mach bootstrap namespace, exception server and security audit session.

I'm not familiar enough with these concepts to tell you exactly what these do, but it was enough to get `pluginkit` working.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the mention, trying it out in a few hours. Curious what did you search for just before finding it?

Comment: Did you enable the root user programatically? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012 Because the su command fails by default "Sorry".

Comment: No, I never did anything like that. I just setup the command to run as a launch daemon. I don't remember ever encountering an issue where su responds "sorry". Sorry I can't give any more help!

Comment: It's fine, figured it out, thanks a bunch for the help! Who knows how much time you saved me. Regards